# Is netbios required with samba -> win7 and what ports are needed for view/read/write functionality?

Tags: firewall, openvpn, samba, port

Basically I do an IT course at my college (United Kingdom) and obviously with it being a college, they have web filters and a restrictive firewall. To bypass the web blocks and to access my rented test server via SSH, I use OpenVPN on port 443 and port sharing to port 22. I would like to be able to access my data at home on my NAS as well. Obviously it will not map as a network location at college due to the restrictive firewall, is it possible for me to use the OpenVPN port sharing or perhaps sslh multiplexer to access the drive on port 443? Or is there any other way I could remotely access the data on my NAS behind this restrictive firewall? As far as we can tell everything is restricted apart from data on ports 80 and 443 i.e web traffic.

EDIT *forgot to mention I use samba on an Arch Linux x86_64 machine for my NAS at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File and printer sharing in Windows is provided by a suite of protocols called [CIFS and also known as SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).

As explained in that article, if you [turn off NetBIOS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940063.aspx), the only thing required for the file sharing to work is port 445/TCP (which should be accessible remotely via your tunnel or by other means).

Don't forget to check firewall setting on your NAS, if applicable, as it might, for instance, "trust" the network it's connected directly and do not trust the network used by OpenVPN to manage the tunnel.